# Cannot export RGB values to CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, rgb

I can export NDVI values to CSV file. But I couldn't export RGB values(b2,,b3,b4) to csv file and RGB values must be in range 0-255.

```js
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[26.9559366037084, 39.42848463948233],
          [26.9559366037084, 39.41562180312237],
          [26.971214466257226, 39.41562180312237],
          [26.971214466257226, 39.42848463948233]]], null, false);

var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-8-31')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',5)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first());

var palette = [
  'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
  '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
  '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301']
  
function addNdvi(img){
    var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('ndvi');
    return img.addBands(ndvi);
  }
  
var ndvi= addNdvi(image.clip(geometry));
  
Map.addLayer(ndvi,{bands: ['ndvi'], palette: palette},'ndvi');
Map.addLayer(image.clip(geometry),{bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max:0.3}, 'rgb');


var ndviFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(ndvi
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 10
  })
  .get('ndvi'))
  .map(function (ndvi) {
    return ee.Feature(null, {ndvi: ndvi})``
  })
)


var rgbFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(image
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 10
  })
  .get('image'))
  .map(function (rgb) {
    return ee.Feature(null, {rgb: rgb})
  })
)


print('# rgb of pixels',rgbFeatures.size())
print('# ndvi of pixels',ndviFeatures.size())


Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: rgbFeatures,
  
  description: 'dene',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']
});


Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndviFeatures,
  description: 'ndvi',
  selectors: ['ndvi']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how you wanted your CSV file to be formatted, so here's one approach simply creating a column for each of the three bands:

```
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4']
var rgbFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(
  image
  .select(bands)
  .multiply(255) // 0-1 to 0-255
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30
  })
  .toArray()
  .transpose()
  .toList()
  .map(function (values) {
    return ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary.fromLists(bands, values))
  })
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fdaa4f571afe0ee931c854b72974f93e